# Turning 18 ...traveling to the UK with a child unaccompanied visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

Basically I have a child unaccompanied visa that I got when I was 17.. but I am18 now, and my visa is valid till 26th of March..so do I need a consent form from parents to travel or nah?

Comment: What is written on your visa?

Comment: Child Unaccompanied.. so I got this visa when I was 17 but I am 18 now..can I still travel alone with it..or do I need a letter of consent?

Comment: @blitkasiyanka As an adult, there's no way you'll need parental consent for anything ever. However, as for whether your visa is still valid, I'd suggest you send an email to public.enquiries@homeoffice.gov.uk **and** ukvigeneral@mailgb.custhelp.com and ask (you can select multiple receipients). If they say you can travel, **print the confirmation**